# Angular router.navigate() delta

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

As described in the manual, `router.navigate` accepts a delta, but the manual but isn't specific enough on that:

> Navigate based on the provided array of commands and a starting point. If no starting route is provided, the navigation is absolute.
>
> ...
>
> In opposite to navigateByUrl, navigate always takes a delta that is applied to the current URL.

Does it just apply a relative URL or something more complex? What kind of delta does it refer to in case of absolute navigation then?

Comment: What is delta?
I just found one place for 'delta' in angular docs,it is one part fo RouterLink API Doc page:

> The router link directive always treats the provided input as a delta to the current url.

> For instance, if the current url is /user/(box//aux:team).

> Then the following link <a [routerLink]="['/user/jim']">Jim</a> will generate the link /user/(jim//aux:team).

See createUrlTree for more information.


'''

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does it just apply a relative URL or something more complex?

It is a relative URL built from the pieces you provide via `commands` param and taking into account additional parameters you pass in `extras` (the [NavigationExtras object](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)).

For example, you can use `relativeTo` to navigate from the active route or from the root route.
You can set the query parameters or fragment for the URL you navigate to (`queryParams` and `fragment` in extras) or you can preserve query parameters that are present in the current url (`queryParamsHandling` in extras).

And so on, so in general, it is actually something more complex than just a navigation by URL as we build the URL dynamically.

> What kind of delta does it refer to in case of absolute navigation then?

It is same for relative and absolute navigation - the delta is the set of changes (`commands`) to apply to the current route (relative) or to the root route (absolute) to transfer the application to the new state (vs just providing the new URL via the `navigateByUrl`).

In the simple case, if you do something like `this.router.navigate(['/heroes'])` it actually is not very different from using the `navigateByUrl`, but consider these examples (see the [createUrlTree](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createUrlTree) which actually converts `commands` and `extras` to the final URL):

```
// create /team/33/(user/11//right:chat)
router.createUrlTree(['/team', 33, {outlets: {primary: 'user/11', right: 'chat'}}]);

// remove the right secondary node
router.createUrlTree(['/team', 33, {outlets: {primary: 'user/11', right: null}}]);
```

So even for the absolute navigation, the `navigate` method provides a set of additional tools to dynamically build the URL. You could do this with `navigateByUrl`, but you would probably parse / concat / do other manipluations with strings (or would develop own tool similar to what `navigate` and `createUrlTree` provide).

Answer (score 2):

in relative mode, the delta is applied to the current route. It natively calls navigateByUrl using this code

````
/**
   * Navigate based on the provided array of commands and a starting point.
   * If no starting route is provided, the navigation is absolute.
   *
   * Returns a promise that:
   * - resolves to 'true' when navigation succeeds,
   * - resolves to 'false' when navigation fails,
   * - is rejected when an error happens.
   *
   * ### Usage
   *
   * ```
   * router.navigate(['team', 33, 'user', 11], {relativeTo: route});
   *
   * // Navigate without updating the URL
   * router.navigate(['team', 33, 'user', 11], {relativeTo: route, skipLocationChange: true});
   * ```
   *
   * In opposite to `navigateByUrl`, `navigate` always takes a delta that is applied to the current
   * URL.
   */
  navigate(commands: any[], extras: NavigationExtras = {skipLocationChange: false}):
      Promise<boolean> {
    validateCommands(commands);
    return this.navigateByUrl(this.createUrlTree(commands, extras), extras);
  }
````

many examples are included in the source code
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts

Comment: The question is *Does it just apply a relative URL or something more complex? What kind of delta does it refer to in case of absolute navigation then?*. It's unclear between what and what this delta is calculated. If it's relative path, they would likely say 'relative path'. I would not put a bounty on something that could be easily figured out from official docs.